# Geometric Brownian Motion with Dividends

Tags: options, monte-carlo, brownian-motion, dividends

I am working on a problem and had a quick question. I understand that for Geometric Brownian Motion we use the formula:

$$X_{t_n} = X_{t_{n-1}} + \mu X_{t_{n-1}} \Delta t + \sigma X_{t_{n-1}} \epsilon_n \sqrt{\Delta t}$$

To my understanding this is for modeling non dividend paying stocks.

How should this formula be amended to allow for say a 2% continuous dividend?

Comment: What do you intend to do with these simulated paths? If this is for pricing, then under the risk-neutral measure your drift $\mu$ should actually be $r-d$ where $r$ is the risk-free rate, and $d$ the continuous dividend yield.

Comment: Yes, it is for pricing. Thank you.